# В чём премущество HEX-формата цвета в HTML перед RGB(A)?

Tags: html, css, color, цвета

Каков выигрыш от использования цвета в шетнадцатиричном (HEX) формате HTML?

Этот формат гораздо труднее для восприятия, чем RGB, да и канала прозрачности нет. Казалось бы, при таком раскладе можно и полностью отказаться он HEX в пользу RGBA, но HEX не только активно используется, но и имеет большую популярность.

Остаётся сделать вывод, что использование цвета в этом формате является приоритетным с точки зрения оптимизации. Верно ли это предположение?

Comment: и тот и другой применяется в html , преимуществ нету

Comment: Этот формат гораздо труднее для восприятия, чем RGB - очень субъективно

Comment: а в чём труднее ?

Comment: #EE7600 тёмно - оранжевый , не проверял но по моему так

Comment: разница лишь в печати , HEX аналогичен CMYK , но отличие только в грубости цвета , все цвета на сайте включая градиент не будет отпечатаны и принтер выведет цвета только в известной ему гамме CMYK , как раз HEX приближен к этой цветовой гамме цвета, RGBA то что есть RED GREEN BLUE + Alpha не выводится печатью , и те страницы которые пишутся с media print должны быть в цветовой гамме HEX

Comment: @LenovoID А разве в HEX цвет задан каналами CMYK а не RGB?

Comment: не то что бы , но приближен к cmyk , именно это цветовая гамма выходит при печати если не указано иное rgb не учитывается , не знаю правда как в современных принтерах , но до 2013 hex очень чётко отпечатывался в них

Comment: @LenovoID Разве hex и rgb не просто разные варианты записи одних и тех же значений? У них разный охват или гамма?

Comment: Kromster , hex и rgb это одно и тоже , но при печати RGB игнорируется а HEX отпечатывается один в один , подразумеваю что как раз из за альфа канала

Comment: @LenovoID Можете привести подтверждение информации? Если да, то это будет хорошим ответом.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос на enSO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171422

Comment: Kromster , у меня 3 принтера , и по началу я извращался с ними , думал что rgba можно отпечатать , а оказалось что нет , почитал мануалы по inscape и там точно указано почему цветовая палитра должна быть для печати именно в HEX или CMYK ,на данный момент я этим уже не занимаюсь , просто знаю и всё , потому и не пишу Ответ а просто комментарий

Comment: "Для восприятия труднее" - да, конечно субъективно, труднее тем, что в RGB используются только цифры, а в HEX - ещё и буквы. Не то, что трудно, непривычно.

Comment: Эти коды цветов должен воспринимать компьютер. А компьютеру-то всё равно. Работает по заложенной в него программе. Тут главное что проще запрограммировать hex или rgb. Что касается дизайнеров, этих художников и креаклов, то они же всё равно пользуются всякими программками, где цвета выбирают из colorpicker, а не вручную и на глаз прикидывают hex или rgb.

Comment: Запись HEX короче. #000 — четыре символа, rgb(0, 0, 0) — 12 символов. Проблема альфа-канала решается использованием препроцессоров. Например, в stylus alpha(#000, .2)

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю всех за интересные ответы, но мы ушли от темы вопроса, потому я не просто задам его заново, а задам по-другому. С какими возможными проблемами я столкнусь, если полностью откажусь от HEX в пользу RGBA при создании сайтов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это почти одно и то же. Просто HEX использует представление в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления (#RRGGBB или #RGB), а rgb в десятичной, что более удобно для человеческого восприятия. Еще в rgb можно указывать значения в процентах `rgb(100%,0%,0%)` и указывать прозрачность `rgba(255,255,255,0.5)`

Comment: Это я уже знаю; мне не совсем понятно почему, не смотря на то, что Вы сказали, цвет в формате HEX всё ещё широко применяется.

Comment: Скорее всего потому что HEX более короткий способ записи.

Comment: Хорошо, я думаю, что закрою эту тему, если получу чёткий ответ на вопрос: можно ли без каких-либо потерь (в быстродейтсвии сайта и т. д.) ПОЛНОСТЬЮ исключить HEX-формат из использования в пользу RGBA?

Comment: Конечно можно. Но RGBA нужно использовать только в тех случаях где нужна прозрачность, в остальных просто RGB.

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю Вас за ответ! Поставлю Вам галочку.